# Creating Kafka Consumer using Payara Cloud

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, payara

```
package com.maersk.inlandmoves.ejb;
    import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
    import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaListener;
    import fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.api.OnRecord;
    @MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "sp-document-processor"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "groupIdConfig", propertyValue = "MSK.inland.AMPSEM.consumerGroup.v1"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "topics", propertyValue = "MSK.Operation.OperationalTransportOrder.topic.confidential.any.v2"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "bootstrapServersConfig", propertyValue = "rp-cde-rpx-stage.crb.apmoller.net:9093"),   
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "autoCommitInterval", propertyValue = "100"),   
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "retryBackoff", propertyValue = "1000"),   
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "keyDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),   
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "valueDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),   
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "pollInterval", propertyValue = "1000"),   
        })
        public class KafkaMDB implements KafkaListener {
             
            @OnRecord( topics={"MSK.Operation.OperationalTransportOrder.topic.confidential.any.v2"})
            public void getMessageTest(ConsumerRecord record) {
                System.out.println("Got record on topic testing " + record);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to create a Kafka consumer using above MDB approach. But I can not seem to change the ConsumerConfig properties as set in the activation property. I see ProducerConfig properties which i have not set(probably has come as part of the rar).
Also I don't know how to set ssl and sasl related properties.
I have deployed the kafka.rar and and have required pom depndencies. Could someone please help.